# How to conduct an Accent Sensitive search in MySql

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I have a MySQL table with utf8 general ci collation. In the table, I can see two entries:

abad
abád

I am using a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT *  FROM `words` WHERE `word` = 'abád'
```

The query result gives both words:

abad
abád

Is there a way to indicate that I only want MySQL to find the accented word? I want the query to only return

abád

I have also tried this query:

```
SELECT *  FROM `words` WHERE BINARY `word` = 'abád'
```

It gives me no results. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

If your searches on that field are always going to be accent-sensitive, then declare the collation of the field as utf8_bin (that'll compare for equality the utf8-encoded bytes) or use a language specific collation that distinguish between the accented and un-accented characters.

```
col_name varchar(10) collate utf8_bin
```

If searches are normally accent-insensitive, but you want to make an exception for this search, try;

```
WHERE col_name = 'abád' collate utf8_bin
```

Update for MySQL 8.0, plus addressing some of the Comments and other Answers:

- The `CHARACTER SET` matches the beginning of the `COLLATION`.
- Any `COLLATION` name ending in `_bin` will ignore both upper/lower case and accents.  Examples:  `latin1_bin`, `utf8mb4_bin`.
- Any `COLLATION` name containing `_as_` will ignore accents, but do case folding or not based on `_ci` vs `_cs`.
- To see the collations available (on any version), do `SHOW COLLATION;`.
- `utf8mb4` is now the default charset.  You should be using that instead of `utf8`.
- It is better to have the `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATION` set 'properly' on each column (or defaulted by the table definition) than to dynamically use any conversion routine such as `CONVERT()`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I'm getting: "COLLATION 'utf8_bin' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'".

Comment: BTW, my character set is really "utf8_general_ci", so I don't know why it says the character set is "latin1".

Comment: @OMA look for the character set and collate for DB, Table and column, all should be the same in order to work properly

Comment: this also works using the LIKE wildcard operator by
`... WHERE CONVERT(field_name USING latin1) like '%á%' COLLATE utf8_bin`

Comment: `COLLATION 'utf8_bin' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'`

Comment: @User Try using `collate utf8mb4_bin` instead.

Comment: @DanBreen Ya, except that has issues on Windows.

Comment: Is there any collation (as of now) which facilitates the CaseInsensitive and AccentSensitive?

Comment: Unrecognized keyword. (near "collate" at position 44)

Answer (score 17):

In my version (MySql 5.0), there is not available any utf8 charset collate for case insensitive, accent sensitive searches. The only accent sensitive collate for utf8 is utf8_bin. However it is also case sensitive.

My work around has been to use something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `words` WHERE LOWER(column) = LOWER('aBád') COLLATE utf8_bin
```

Comment: `#1253 - COLLATION 'utf8_bin' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' `

Comment: Then you should use utf8mb4_bin.

Comment: if you want to make it both-side-case-insensitive, don't forget to also `LOWER('the_searched_value')` so you will get `LOWER(column) = LOWER('aBád')`

Comment: I also had to use utf8mb4_bin... this was for an "inline query" in phpMyAdmin.  Wonder where and why these CHARACTER SETs are set...?

Answer (score 6):

Accepted answer is good, but beware that you may have to use COLLATE utf8mb4_bin instead!

```
WHERE col_name = 'abád' collate utf8mb4_bin
```

Above fixes errors like:

> MySQL said: Documentation 1253 - COLLATION 'utf8_bin' is not valid for
>   CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'

Answer (score 3):

The MySQL bug, for future reference, is http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=19567.

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if the database table collation type end with "_ci", This stands for case insensitive...

Change it to collation the same or nearest name without the "_ci" ...

For example... change "utf8_general_ci" to "utf8_bin"
Mke

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error.

I've changed the collation of my table to utf8_bin (through phpMyAdmin) and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *  FROM `words` WHERE column = 'abád' collate latin1_General_CS
```

(or your collation including cs)

Answer (score 0):

You can try searching for the hex variable of the character, HEX() within mysql and use a similar function within your programming language and match these. This worked well for me when i was doing a listing where a person could select the first letter of a person.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you just described what utf8_general_ci collation is all about (a, á, à, â, ä, å all equals to a in comparison).

There have also been changes in MySQL server 5.1 in regards to utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci so it's server version dependent too. Better check the docs.

So, If it's MySQL server 5.0 I'd go for utf8_unicode_ci instead of utf8_general_ci which is obviously wrong for your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

That works for me for an accent insensitive and case insensitive search in MySql server 5.1 in a database in utf8_general_ci, where column is a LONGBLOB.

```
select * from words where '%word%' LIKE column collate utf8_unicode_ci
```

with

```
select * from words where'%word%' LIKE column collate utf8_general_ci
```

the result is case sensitive but not accent sensitive.