# php, mysql: compare strings - accent sensitive and case insensitive

Tags: php, mysql, case-insensitive, non-ascii-characters

i need to perform a name search in the database based on a set of keywords. the result should be accent sensitive and case insensitive.

following the solution i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500826/how-to-conduct-an-accent-sensitive-search-in-mysql) plus few modifications to allow case insensitivity, i used the following code:

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM table_names WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE _utf8 '%".strtolower($keyword)."%' COLLATE utf8_bin";
```

this does not work for me when the search keyword contains accents. but the strange thing is that this query works well in phpMyAdmin (but i read somewhere that this shouldn't be reliable). what could be the problem here?

UPDATE:
i revised my code to:

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM table_names WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER(_utf8 '%$keyword%') COLLATE utf8_bin";
```

but i still have no results.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to echo the sql being executed and check if the accents are there.

My guess they are not...

**[EDIT]**

Can you try this:

php.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<form action="" method="get">
<input name="name" type="text"/>
<input type="submit" value="go"/>
</form>

<?php
if (!empty($_GET['name'])) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
    $mysqli->set_charset('latin1');

    $_GET['name'] = utf8_encode($_GET['name']);

    if ($result = $mysqli->query('select * from dummy where LOWER(name) LIKE _utf8 \'%' . $_GET['name'] . '%\' COLLATE utf8_bin')) {
        while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) { 
            var_dump($obj->name); 
        }
    }
    $mysqli->close();
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

mysql: (doesn't matter)

```
CREATE TABLE `dummy` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin5$$
```

This one works for me...

Comment: i tried echoing it and the accents are there. the echoed statement was also the query i used to run in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: thanks! but i can't set my table's collation to utf8_bin as it has to be case and accent insensitive. i only have one instance in which i have to make an accent sensitive comparison..