# MySQL Collate Latin1_General_CI_AI Problem

Tags: mysql, collate

I have the following select statement where I'm trying to search for a players first and last name that may contain accents in it.

```
$sql = "
    SELECT * FROM player
    WHERE player.player_first LIKE '%$first%'
    AND player.player_last LIKE '%$last%'
    ";
```

I adding `COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI` after before both of the LIKE clauses, but that didn't work and returned errors.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unknown collation: 'Latin1_General_CI_AI'

Answer (score 1):

According to [MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/charset-mysql.html) the collation `Latin1_General_CI_AI` does not exists.

Try `latin1_general_ci` instead.

Comment: I thought AI did exist though because the AI meant it was accent insensitive, that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: After some searches, the only AI + CI collation in MySQL seems to be `utf8_general_ci`. Check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collation-implementations.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500826/how-to-conduct-an-accent-sensitive-search-in-mysql. But I guess that your DB charset must be UTF8 then.