# MySQL - How to use SELECT to get only special characters in UTF8

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'am trying to SELECT a cloumn in the table which contains only vowels. It works fine till I try to select entries with german umlauts (special chars like ä,ö,ü), then the query makes no difference between u<->ü, o<->ö, a<->ä

```
SELECT vowels 
FROM words
WHERE vowels LIKE 'ü'
// this also selects all entries with simple 'u'
```

Collation of the database is UTF8, document is formatted in UTF8, I'am using $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

Any ideas how to get that working? Thanks!

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500826/how-to-conduct-an-accent-sensitive-search-in-mysql

Comment: Do you want case insensitivity?

Comment: someone know how mysql nows that `ü` -> `u` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way is to use the `utf8_bin` collation.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `COLLATE` to change the collation on the fly

```
SELECT vowels COLLATE utf8_bin as vowel
FROM words
WHERE vowel LIKE 'ü'
```

not tested