# Search the French Accents in MySql

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to conduct an Accent Sensitive search in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500826/how-to-conduct-an-accent-sensitive-search-in-mysql)

I have a MySQL database which consists of list of words which contain both French and English Letters in a table.

**Ex :**
Datas Stored in DB as like :

### id | words

1. rççl
2. rççr
3. rçgi

I have searched for a query like this

```
 SELECT id, words  FROM `dictionary` WHERE `words` LIKE '_ç__'
```

### So i got the following result
id | words

1. rççl
2. rççr
3. rçgi

In that query i have searched for french letter. SO the result is correct.

but in case i have searched for the following query,

```
SELECT id, words  FROM `dictionary` WHERE `words` LIKE '_c__'
```

### the result is the same
id | words

1. rççl
2. rççr
3. rçgi

**So My Question is how to differentiate with this letters and what i need to change in my program or query? PLease Help ?**

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use a [COLLATE clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html) with whatever chosen [case sensitivity/binary format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collation-names.html) sorry, I do not know the best collation for French accents.