# Doctrine2 accents-insensitive search in DQL

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dql, mysql5

I didn't find anything good on that topic. Im currently implementing simple search function with will use LIKE to find requested records. But I wan't to make "accents-free" search.

For example:
object name is: "Gdańsk", it should be found by string "Gdansk" and "Gdańsk".

If it was the other way around, it would be as simple as transforming search string, but since we have to transform the original value before comparision then it's little more diffcult.

Any help would be welcome.

Im using MySQL 5.5.

Comment: Isn't that related just with MySQL?

Comment: I had hope that it will not come to that and Doctrine has some nice solution.

Comment: I don't have any solution purely with Doctrine, but with MySQL you can have a look to collations.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to MySQL only. See:

[How to conduct an Accent Sensitive search in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500826/how-to-conduct-an-accent-sensitive-search-in-mysql)

If you want an *accent insensitive* search, then use `utf8_general_ci` as your database collation.