# Codeigniter 2.1, MySQL - search with serbian characters

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have search query that do the search by specific words, and sometimes there is a collision because some Serbian and English words are spelled similar. For example word **cilim** and **ćilim**. When search is done for this two words I always get result for the word **cilim**. It seems that MySQL reads letters **c** and **ć** as same one. DB is set to **utf8_general_ci** and in **database** config file I got this part **$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';**. How can I make MySQL search by Serbian characters?

Comment: is your php<->mysql connection in utf-8 as well? if it's not, the chars may be utf in php, but they'll get mangled on the wire.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/501151/1385783