# mysql collation and grouping: how to ungroup lower, uppercased and accents?

Tags: mysql

```
select count(answer1) as total, questionsResults.answer1 
    from questionsResults
    WHERE correct=1 GROUP by answer1
```

My problem is that this groups lowercases and uppercases and even removes accents !

```
Bonjour pépé
bonjour pépé
Bonjour pepe
```

will all be grouped together : it will give me 1 row whereas I need 3 rows: I need distinguish lowercases, uppercases and even accents !

Any clue ?

Comment: Try looking at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500826/how-to-conduct-an-accent-sensitive-search-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

From the manual

> With the COLLATE clause, you can override whatever the default
>   collation is for a comparison. COLLATE may be used in various parts of
>   SQL statements.

This behaviour depends on the collocation in use.

The collocation you need is utf_bin.

You can directly specify it in the query using COLLATE

```
select count(answer1) as total, questionsResults.answer1 
from questionsResults
WHERE correct=1 GROUP by answer1 COLLATE 'utf8_bin'
```

The documentation can be found here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html

of course you can also modify the collocation in your database.

The other way round, grouping by it can be enforced as follows
(this was my original answer, i mis understood the question. But for completeness i will leave it)

You can use string functions in your query.

Something like:

```
GROUP by replace(lower(answer1),'é',e)
```

If this is french, than not so much accents are possible so this is a solution.

You can also import functions into mysql, for example this one: https://github.com/falcacibar/mysql-routines-collection/blob/master/tr.func.sql (MySQL UDF implementation of strtr C function)

Or you could normalize the data before inserting it.

Comment: I need the CONTRARY: I need to UNGROUP.
Now mysql groups them autoamtcailly and I need to ungroup that !

Comment: oh sorry, i adapt my answer! just give me a sec