# sql collations with php that uses none-english alphabet

Tags: mysql

I use : **`Ûû-Şş-Çç-Êê-Îî` + [A-z]** in Mysql database[Kurdish Alphabet].

The problem is that when I search for something like :

```
select * from test where col like '`ç`%'
```

The results is like:

`ç`= c
, `û`= u
, `ş`= s
, `î`= i
, `ê`= e

What collation or trick should I use to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `... collate utf8_bin`:

```
select * from test where col like 'ç%' collate utf8_bin;
```

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500826/how-to-conduct-an-accent-sensitive-search-in-mysql) and this [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fea7c/3) as well.