# select distinct exactly word utf8 in mysql

Tags: mysql, utf-8, distinct

I have a query like this :

```
Select distinct keyword from keyword_table
```

With two keywords : `cafe, café`. That query only choose one. I want it only distinct two keyword `cafe` ( not `café`) . How can I do? Column's collation is `utf8_unicode_ci`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to conduct an Accent Sensitive search in MySql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500826/how-to-conduct-an-accent-sensitive-search-in-mysql)

Comment: Unclear -- do you want 1 row or 2?