# Select from several outputs the one with special characters in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters, fetch, collation

In my database I have two forms of the same word. So for example when I search for `amor` I get `amor` and `āmōr`. How can I fetch just `āmōr` from the database.

Comment: And your current `COLLATION` is?  Take a look at `utf8_bin` and read up on fulltext search in general.  Possible Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500826/how-to-conduct-an-accent-sensitive-search-in-mysql

Comment: @ficuscr In my case I have the input 'amor' without special characters and I am searching for the form 'āmōr'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to mess around with Collation (for some reason):

```
SELECT a.text
FROM table a
WHERE a.text = 'amor'
AND BINARY(a.text) = BINARY('amor')
```

I left the first condition with the plain text so that MySQL can use an index on `text`, in case that exists. The second condition will make sure you are only getting the exact text (including capitalization) you searched for.

**EDIT:** Based on comment.

If you do want to get the accented result, you need to use a collation that ignores such accents. The one you need to use depends on the collation of the column..

Try any of the below:

```
SELECT a.text
FROM table a
WHERE a.text = 'amor'
COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';
```

Or:

```
SELECT a.text
FROM table a
WHERE a.text = 'amor'
COLLATE 'latin1_general_ci';
```

**EDIT #2:** Based on more comments.

To always get the accented version in case there is more than one match:

```
SELECT a.text
FROM table a
WHERE a.text = 'amor' -- this condition returns both results
ORDER BY LENGTH(BINARY(a.text)) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This would not work in my case because I am not searching the exact input. I am looking for a possibility where I can input the normal "amor" and I get the "āmōr" with special characters.

Comment: for 'utf8_general_ci' the query does not work, for 'latin1_general_ci' I still get both results...

Comment: @ChrisWinterbottom - I thought you want both results! So you want to search for 'amor', and only get the accented result even though both exist? What's the logic? What would you want to get if there are 3 versions that match? Usually the options are either the exact match or all matches....

Comment: The logic behind it would be that for example someone is searching a word in the Dictionary(the db) and he cannot type in the form with the special characters because of his keyboard...and no, in the db there are only two different matches.

Comment: @ChrisWinterbottom - but how do you know if they meant "āmōr" and could not type it, or just meant "amor"? Why is the "āmōr" result better?

Comment: Yes, I know that they meant "āmōr" because in poetry you only need "āmōr".

Comment: @ChrisWinterbottom that's a very specific use case though. If you change your query specifically for this, how about other queries with a similar issue, where it's not clear that only one is used in poetry?

Comment: @ChrisWinterbottom - what is the rule you want in the query? Is it (a) "if user search for 'amor', return āmōr", or (b) "if user searched for a string with no accents, and there's a match with accents, return the match with accents"

Comment: @ChrisWinterbottom - please see if latest edit helps.

Comment: For the last edit...how can I search in several fields?