# MySQL Database why do Õ come back as O when Search

Tags: mysql, utf-8, collation

i have multiple special characters `(Õ)` in my table column 
When i search for `Õ` its showing O also in search results.

```
select * from table where column like '%Õ%'
```

i want to replace `Õ` with single Question in my Table.
Example : its saving as below

It`Õ`s going to be just one of the factors that will be the cause of the resistance

> so figure out which one it is and focus on that one.

Comment: update table set column = replace('Õ','?') where column like '%Õ%';

Comment: Did you even search for "mysql string replace" before posting your question?

Comment: @SloanThrasher when i search it showing the O letter results as well Ex:Object,Oppostite,NÕ,NanÕ,  etc..  i want to get only `Õ` these results.

Comment: Your question is `why do Õ come back as O?` or `How can I replace Õ with O?`?

Comment: See if the answer by O. Jones works for your data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401771/how-can-i-find-non-ascii-characters-in-mysql

Comment: @chris85 Type: `MySAM`  Collation:`utf8_general_ci`

Comment: @chris85 my question is How can I replace Õ with with single quotation `'`

Comment: @SloanThrasher first comment is pretty close to what you need, `update table set column = replace(column, 'Õ', "'") where column like '%Õ%'`.

Comment: @chris85 before update i want to select the data how can i search that data

Comment: Use a `select` in place of the `update` you can use the `replace` in the `select` and it will show you what it will do. `select column as original_data, replace(column, 'Õ', "'") as new_data from table where column like '%Õ%'` Replace `column` and `table` in all instances with your real names.

Comment: @chris85, when i `select * from table where column like '%Õ%'` then its showing the results contains O instead of Õ.

Comment: Then the question was/is `why do Õ come back as O?`... I think the collation you are using may be accent insensitive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to conduct an Accent Sensitive search in MySql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500826/how-to-conduct-an-accent-sensitive-search-in-mysql)

Comment: Where did the `Õ` come from?  Maybe it would be better to _prevent_ it than to _fix_ it?

Comment: Is this related?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43299426/how-to-retrive-the-data-if-it-is-special-charecter-%c3%95

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using utf8 currently:

```
mysql> SELECT REPLACE('O-o-Õ-Õ-x', 'Õ', '?') COLLATE utf8_bin;
+----------------------------------------------------+
| REPLACE('O-o-Õ-Õ-x', 'Õ', '?') COLLATE utf8_bin    |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| O-o-?-?-x                                          |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Notice how it replaced only the `Õ` characters.

If you are using utf8mb4, then change to `COLLATE utf8mb4_bin`.

Caution -- Your problem is very unusual.  If you have left out some aspects of the problem, this solution may do more harm than good.