# How to retrive the data if it is special charecter (Õ)..?

Tags: php, html, mysql, character-encoding

In my database I have **DONT** word..

In database it is stored like this:**DÕNT**  Due to that `Õ` the data is not coming..!

How can i retrive that..?
This my code of retrive:

```
htmlspecialchars($res_get_option['answer']);
```

Collation: **Null**  and Type: **MyISAM**

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What do you mean by "retrieve"? Do you mean you can't SELECT the row when comparing against the string "DONT"?

Comment: In my database there is column name `answer` i want to fetch that column data from database. @SloanThrasher

Comment: Most or all of the answers can be found in this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through - which risks to be a duplicate.

Comment: also, without seeing any other code that is relevant to the problem, we don't know if what you're using is right or if something is missing.

Comment: Where did the `Õ` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set right collation for database and update wrong characters, with right ones, using a script for this.

Comment: @Ozgur okay what is that script..? and what do i need to update in collation..?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed Script must be written, which selects all rows, replacing characters using str_replace function and finally updates all rows

Comment: can you please write that here for me that is what im not getting it.. and what do i need to update in collation @ozgur

Comment: @AbdulWaheed how many rows will be updated? If it's not much, it can be done manually using phpmyadmin