# Search mysql for similar unicode characters

Tags: mysql, unicode, ascii

I am trying to create a search function in mysql that searches simular unicode character,

So for example when I search for a city 'Amsterdam' by search-string 'amster', I want the following all to return the same results:

```
> - select * from table where city like '%amster%' (latin)
> - select * from table where city like '%ΆμσtER%' (greek mixed with latin combined)
> - select * from table where city like '%Амстер%' (full unicode)
> - select * from table where city like '%àмstÉr%' (with accents)
```

I tried to create a mysql function that translates all characters into their ASCII counterparts. For example 'σ'(greek), 'с'(cyrillic), š, ś, Ş all become a latin 's'. The function works fine but is so slow that it renders large searches useless. The function is :

```
CREATE FUNCTION englishfyString(INPUT varchar(250)) 
        RETURNS VARCHAR(250)
        BEGIN
                DECLARE OUTPUT VARCHAR(250);
                
                DECLARE len1 INT(4) DEFAULT 0;
                DECLARE pos1 INT(4) DEFAULT 1;
                DECLARE letter1 CHAR(4);
                
                DECLARE len2 INT(4) DEFAULT 0;
                DECLARE pos2 INT(4) DEFAULT 0;
                DECLARE letter2 CHAR(4);

                DECLARE string_a CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_ae CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_b CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_c CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_ch CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_d CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_dz CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_e CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_f CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_g CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_h CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_i CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_j CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_k CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_l CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_ll CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_m CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_n CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_nj CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_ny CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_o CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_p CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_ps CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_r CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_s CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_sh CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_ss CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_sz CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_t CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_th CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_ts CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_u CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_v CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_w CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_x CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_y CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_ya CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_ye CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_yo CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_yu CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_z CHAR(250);
                DECLARE string_null CHAR(250);
                

                SET OUTPUT = '';
                SET INPUT = TRIM(LOWER(INPUT));     
                SET len1 =   CHAR_LENGTH(INPUT);

                SET string_null=    FROM_BASE64('0YzRig==');    
                SET string_a =      FROM_BASE64('0LDOsc6syZnDocOgw6LHjsSDw6PhuqPIp+G6ocOkw6XhuIHEgcSF4baP4rGlyIHhuqXhuqfhuqvhuqnhuq3huq/hurHhurXhurPhurfHu8ehx5/IgciDyZHhtIDJkA==');
                SET string_ae =     FROM_BASE64('w6bHvcej');
                SET string_b =      FROM_BASE64('0LHOsmLhuIPhuIXhuIfGgMmTxoPhtoDIuA==');
                SET string_c =      FROM_BASE64('xIfEicSNxItjzITDp+G4ici8xojhtIQ=');
                SET string_ch =     FROM_BASE64('0YfRhc+H0Zs=');
                SET string_d =      FROM_BASE64('0LTOtMSRxI/huIvhuJHhuI3huJPhuI/EkcOwZMymyZbJl8aM4bWt4baB4baR');
                SET string_dz =     FROM_BASE64('0Z8=');
                SET string_e =      FROM_BASE64('w6nDqMOq4biZxJvEleG6veG4m+G6u8SXw6vEk8ipxJnhtpLJh8iF4bq/4buB4buF4buD4bid4biX4biVyIfhurnhu4fFk+G1q9C10Y3OtdGUzq3EleKxuOKCrA==');
                SET string_f =      FROM_BASE64('0YTPhuG4n8aS4bWu4baC');
                SET string_g =      FROM_BASE64('0LPOs9KRx7XEn8Sdx6fEocSj4bihx6XJoOG2g8mixYs=');
                SET string_h =      FROM_BASE64('xKXIn+G4p+G4o+G4qeG4peG4q+G6lsSn4rGoyaY=');
                SET string_i =      FROM_BASE64('0LjRi9GWzrfOrsOtw6zErcOux5DDr+G4r8SpxK/Eq+G7iciJyIvhu4vhuK3JqOG1u+G2lmnEscmqzq/OuQ==');
                SET string_j =      FROM_BASE64('0ZLRmMS1yYnHsMi3yp3Jn8qE4bSK');
                SET string_k =      FROM_BASE64('0LrOusS34bixx6nEt+G4s+G4tcaZ4rGq4baE6p2B');
                SET string_l =      FROM_BASE64('0LvOu8S6xL7EvOG4t+G4ueG4veG4u8WCxYDGmuKxoQ==');
                SET string_ll =     FROM_BASE64('0Zk=');
                SET string_m =      FROM_BASE64('0LzOvOG4v+G5geG5g+G1r+G2hsmx');
                SET string_n =      FROM_BASE64('0L3OvcWIw7HFhMe5xYjDseG5hcWG4bmH4bmL4bmJbsyIybLGnuG1sOG2h8mzyLU=');
                SET string_nj =     FROM_BASE64('0Zo=');
                SET string_ny =     FROM_BASE64('xYQ=');
                SET string_o =      FROM_BASE64('0L7Ov8+Jz47Ds8OyxY/DtOG7keG7k+G7l+G7lceSw7bIq8WRw7XhuY3huY/IrcivyLHDuMe/x6vHrcWN4bmT4bmR4buPyI3Ij8ah4bub4bud4buh4buf4buj4buN4buZybXisbrhtI/PjA==');
                SET string_p =      FROM_BASE64('0L/PgOG5leG5l+G1vcalcMyD4bWx4baI4bSY');
                SET string_ps =     FROM_BASE64('z4g=');
                SET string_r =      FROM_BASE64('0YDPgcWZxZXFmeG5mcWXyJHIk+G5m+G5neG5n8mN');
                SET string_s =      FROM_BASE64('0YHPg8+Cxb/Fm+G5pcWdxaHhuafhuaHhupvFn+G5o+G5qciZc8yp4bW04baKyoLIv+qcsQ==');
                SET string_sh =     FROM_BASE64('0YjRiQ==');
                SET string_ss =     FROM_BASE64('w58=');
                SET string_sz =     FROM_BASE64('0LY=');
                SET string_t =      FROM_BASE64('0YLPhMibxaXhuavFo+G5rcib4bmx4bmvxafisabGrcqI4bqX4bW1xqvItg==');
                SET string_th =     FROM_BASE64('zrjDkMO+w54=');
                SET string_ts =     FROM_BASE64('0YY=');
                SET string_u =      FROM_BASE64('0YPPhcO6w7nFrcO7x5TFr8O8x5jHnMeax5bFscWp4bm5xbPFq+G5u+G7p8iVyJfGsOG7qeG7q+G7r+G7reG7seG7peG5s+G5t+G5tcqJ4bW+4baZ4bScz40=');
                SET string_v =      FROM_BASE64('0LLhub3hub/Ki+G2jOKxseKxtOG0oNCy');
                SET string_w =      FROM_BASE64('xYLhuoPhuoHFteG6heG6h+G6ieG6mOKxs+G0oQ==');
                SET string_x =      FROM_BASE64('zr4=');
                SET string_y =      FROM_BASE64('0LnDvcO94buzxbfhupnDv+G7ueG6j8iz4bu34bu1yY/GtMqP');
                SET string_ya =     FROM_BASE64('0Y8=');
                SET string_ye =     FROM_BASE64('0Zc=');
                SET string_yo =     FROM_BASE64('0ZE=');
                SET string_yu =     FROM_BASE64('0Y4=');
                SET string_z =      FROM_BASE64('0LfOtsW8xbrhupHFvsW84bqT4bqVxrbIpeKxrOG1tuG2jsqQypHJgOG0og==');
            
        
            WHILE(pos1 <= len1) DO
                SET letter1 =   SUBSTRING(INPUT, pos1, 1);

                CASE
                WHEN length(trim(letter1)) > 0 THEN

                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_null)>0,'',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_a)>0,'a',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_ae)>0,'ae',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_b)>0,'b',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_c)>0,'c',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_ch)>0,'ch',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_d)>0,'d',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_dz)>0,'dz',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_e)>0,'e',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_f)>0,'f',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_g)>0,'g',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_h)>0,'h',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_i)>0,'i',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_j)>0,'j',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_k)>0,'k',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_l)>0,'l',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_ll)>0,'ll',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_m)>0,'m',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_n)>0,'n',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_nj)>0,'nj',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_ny)>0,'ny',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_o)>0,'o',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_p)>0,'p',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_ps)>0,'ps',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_r)>0,'r',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_s)>0,'s',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_sh)>0,'sh',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_ss)>0,'ss',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_sz)>0,'sz',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_t)>0,'t',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_th)>0,'th',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_ts)>0,'ts',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_u)>0,'u',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_v)>0,'v',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_w)>0,'w',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_x)>0,'x',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_y)>0,'y',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_ya)>0,'ya',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_ye)>0,'ye',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_yo)>0,'yo',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_yu)>0,'yu',letter1);
                set letter1 =if(LOCATE(letter1,string_z)>0,'z',letter1);

                ELSE
                set letter1 = '';
                
                END CASE;

                SET pos1 =      pos1 + 1;
                SET OUTPUT =    concat(OUTPUT,letter1,'');
                
                
                
            END WHILE;
                
            
            RETURN (OUTPUT);
        END
```

Is there a correct way to perform a search on similar characters in mysql? If not, is there a way to increase the performance of the function?

thank you

Comment: While some of your criterias can be done by choosing an appropriate charset/collation (basically the opposite of [How to conduct an Accent Sensitive search in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500826)), with your very extensive list you are probably best off by just storing a "clean" searchable version of your string in the database (e.g. add a trigger, and when you modify your original field, update the "clean" field using your function) and search in that field.

Answer (score 0):

A database is a data repository, not a programming engine.

I strongly suggest you add a column to your table, then make a pass over the data to convert to "ascii" the real column.  *Do this in application code, not SQL*.

Then, when doing a search, apply the same *application code* to the search string and search the ascii column.

And `INDEX` that new column.

You may choose to store the transliteration in a MySQL table.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out the available collations to see which ones come "close enough".  I doubt if any do, and I doubt if your latinization will always work, either.

If you are using MySQL 8.0, I suggest simply setting the collation for the column to `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`.

For older versions, try `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`.  Here is a list of equivalences, but it does not include Greek or Cyrillic:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html

For 8.0:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8mb4_collations.html