# How to sql search for the letter 'å'

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to search through a MySQL table to find a specific column (as i have done many times before), but I have run into a problem, where I'm trying to search for the letter 'å', but it returns both a column with the letter 'å' and also a column with the letter 'a'.

for example.

I have a table named `Categories` that looks like this:

```
+----------+--------+
| Category | Answer |
+----------+--------+
|  cities  | abenra |
+----------+--------+
|  cities  | åbenrå |
+----------+--------+
```

When I then try to search through it like this
`SELECT * FROM Categories WHERE Category='cities' AND Answer='åbenrå'`
It returns the results:

```
+----------+--------+
| Category | Answer |
+----------+--------+
|  cities  | abenra |
+----------+--------+
|  cities  | åbenrå |
+----------+--------+
```

And what I was expecting and wanted was a result that looks like this:

```
+----------+--------+
| Category | Answer |
+----------+--------+
|  cities  | åbenrå |
+----------+--------+
```

So... How can I search for the letter 'å', without searching for the letter 'a' at the same time?

I really hope that you can help me!
Thanks in regards.

Comment: Specify a Danish locale/collation etc? (In English, å is considered as a (strange) a.)

Comment: @jarlh I have tried that, but I get the same result

Comment: Try looking at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500826/how-to-conduct-an-accent-sensitive-search-in-mysql

Comment: Do you want `ÅBENRÅ` to be returned? And `Aabenrå`?

Comment: When searching "åbenrå" I only want "åbenrå" to be returned, not anything else

Comment: But can't that Danish city be spelled both as Aabenraa and Åbenrå?

Comment: True, but that is handled in another script.

Comment: I'd consider one script only, for all spellings at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need to apply a conversion on your keyword for exact match

```
SELECT * FROM Categories 
WHERE Category='cities' 
AND Answer = CONVERT('åbenrå' USING binary)
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61b16c/6)